# How to deal with \cellcolor and \multicolumn in a complicated table?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, cellcolor

I am preparing an application for a European innovation project call, using the H2020prposal.cls template. However some of the tables built by using the class have (stupidly) changed shape in the official template supplied, and I am trying to mimic one that is strange. I am facing difficulties in coloring the lower cells. By trial and error, I could manage to fill properly both upper and lower cells of the column4, but this is not clean, and every change of document margin affects the results and the upper and lower cells are not evenly filled. What would be a cleaner way ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=15 mm, right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.98\textwidth}{|>{\centering}p{4.5em}|p{12em}|>{\centering}p{5em}|>{\centering}p{4.5em}|>{\centering}p{4.5em}|>{\centering}p{4.5em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!40} \textbf{Work package N°} 
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{Work package title} 
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{Lead participant N°}
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{Lead Participant Short Name}
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{Person Months} 
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{Start month} 
&\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{End Month}\\
\hline
\textbf{WP1}& MANAGEMENT WORK PACKAGE& 1 & TOE & 4 & 1 & 16  \\
\hline
\textbf{WP1}& DEVELOPMENT WORK PACKAGE& 2 & ARC & 8 & 1 & 8  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3} {l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{|> {\raggedleft}p{4.5em}|} {\cellcolor{gray!40} \textbf{Total person month:}} &\multicolumn{1} {c|}{55} &\multicolumn{2} {l}{}\\
\cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{3} {l|}{}  & \multicolumn{2} {> {\raggedleft}p{10em}|}{\cellcolor{gray!40} \textbf{Overall Start and End Months foreseen:}} & 1& 24 \\
\cline{4-7}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Not if the two inner || should vanish (which are specified in the tabular preamble)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300994/eliminating-little-white-vertical-lines-in-tabular-caused-by-colortbl-colorcell

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the new package `tabularray`.

It is very easy to customize your table with it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=15 mm, right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    width=0.97\linewidth,
    colspec={Q[c,4.5em]Q[12em]Q[c,5em]|Q[c,4.5em]Q[c,4.5em]|Q[c,4.5em]X[c]}, vline{1-3}={1-3}{solid},vline{1-3}={1-3}{solid},
    vline{5}={1-4}{solid},vline{7-8}={1-3,5}{solid},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries, gray!40},
    cell{4}{4} = {r=1,c=1}{r,font=\bfseries, gray!40},
    cell{5}{4} = {r=1,c=2}{r, wd=9em,font=\bfseries, gray!40}
    }
\hline
Work package N° 
& Work package title 
& Lead participant N°
& Lead Participant Short Name
& Person Months 
& Start month 
& End Month\\
\hline
WP1& MANAGEMENT WORK PACKAGE& 1 & TOE & 4 & 1 & 16  \\
\hline
WP1& DEVELOPMENT WORK PACKAGE& 2 & ARC & 8 & 1 & 8  \\
\hline
&& & Total person month: &55 &&\\
\cline{4-7}
&&& Overall Start and End Months foreseen: && 1& 24 \\
\cline{4-7}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]