# Table without thin vertical lines in Tabularx (Table in style of ACS Macro Letter journal)

Tags: tables

In this Thread (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301036/229635) it was explained how to make the small vertical lines between two cells disappear by using tabularx and \columncolor and changing the overhang parameters within a multicolumn.

Now I am looking for a way how to create a Table like shown in the picture attached to this post.

The reason why I am asking for your help is that the code updated on August 7th 2020 by Bernard (see link above) doesn't create a table fitting to the text width of my document.

In other words: Is there a way to get rid of all the absolute values and the multicolumn used in the m{} parameters so that the table fits still the textwidth no matter how many columns the table has while still implementing the overhang parameter for color fill to avoid the thin white lines between the cells?
I Want to create a Table having no gridlines and a light gray head row without the small vertical lines between color filled cells while using \cellcolor.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Benson_G

Picture Reference:
Worm, M.; Leibig, D.; Dingels, C.; Frey, H. Cleavable Polyethylene Glycol: 3,4-Epoxy-1-butene as a Comonomer to Establish Degradability at Physiologically Relevant pH.ACS Macro Letters2016,5(12), 1357–1363

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrartcl} %Art des Dokuments, Schriftgröße etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Direkte Angabe von Umlauten möglich 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includehead]{geometry}%Maße für die wissenschaftliche Arbeit
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} %Bessere Seitenumbrüche
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Silbentrennung
\usepackage[english]{babel} %Sprachanpassungen
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einfügen von Bildern
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs} %Weitere Möglichkeiten für Tabellen
\usepackage{here} %Lage von Tabellen und Bildern 
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  %% be sure to specify the option 'hyphens'
% \usepackage[pdftex,bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} %Summenformeln angeben
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[per-mode = reciprocal, output-decimal-marker={,}, exponent-product = {\cdot}]{siunitx} %Si-Einheiten
% \usepackage[colorlinks,
% pdfpagelabels,
% pdfstartview = FitH,
% bookmarksopen = true,
% bookmarksnumbered = true,
% linkcolor = black,
% plainpages = false,
% hypertexnames = false,
% citecolor = black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.90,0.90,0.90}

\newcommand{\RM}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1{.}}}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=scheme,                         % Name der Umgebung
  types=schemes,                       % Erweiterung (\listofschemes)
  float,                               % soll gleiten
  floatpos=tbp,                        % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
  name=Scheme,                         % Name in Überschriften
  listname={Verzeichnis der Schemata}, % Listenname
                                       % counterwithin=chapter
]{los}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\vspace{-1.8 \baselineskip}
  \centering
  \setlength\belowcaptionskip{5 pt}
  \caption{\textbf{Reaction mixture used for the synthesis of cyclohexanone 4-nitrophenylhydrazone.}}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}  
     \cellcolor{hellgrau} chemicals   &\cellcolor{hellgrau} \textit{M} $^a$ (g mol$^{\text{-1}}$)  &\cellcolor{hellgrau} \textit{n} $^a$(mol 10$^{\text{-4}}$)  &\cellcolor{hellgrau} \textit{V} $^a$ (mL) &\cellcolor{hellgrau}  \textit{m} $^a$ (g) &\cellcolor{hellgrau} $\varrho$ $^a$ (g mL$^{\text{-1}}$)\\
    Cyclohexanone               & 98.14   &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{0.5 mL of the destillate}    \\
    4-Nitrophenyl hydrazine     & 153.14  &  26    &   -  & 0.4   & -     \\
    Sulfuric acid               & 98.08   &  372   &   2  & 3.68  & 1.84 \\
    Water                       & 18.02   & 1664   &   3  & 3     & 1.00 \\
    Ethanol                     & 47.07   & 1678   &   10 & 7.9   & 0.79    \\
    \end{tabular} 
    \vspace{0.6 \baselineskip} \\
    \raggedright
    $^a$Molecular mass \textit{M}, amount of substance \textit{n}, volume \textit{V}, mass \textit{m},  density $\varrho$.
  \label{tab:ReactionMixtureCyclohexanone4-nitrophenylhydrazone}%
  \vspace{-1.8 \baselineskip}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide Minimal Working Example (MWE), which reproduce your problem. From your description is not clear, what you doing that you are not happy with the result.

Comment: Okay so here is my MWE. The problem with this is that is doesn't fit the text width and it has these thin vertical white lines between the cells in the light grey head row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- from your document example I try to make MWE (Minimal Working Example),therefore from your example are removed all packages and settings not related to your problem
- to old version of packages or even deprecated are indicated and replaced with recent one
- for table is used `tabularx` environment, its width is set to `\textwidth`, so using them is solved your problem that table width should be equal to `\textwidth`
- for columns with numbers are used `S` columns, defined in `siunitx` package, which enable align numbers at their decimal points
- since I suspect, that you in table headers indicate "footnotes", I suggest that for this is better use `tnotes` defined in the `threeparttable` and for descriptions of their meaning use `table notes`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, 
               enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrartcl} %Art des Dokuments, Schriftgröße etc.
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin=2cm,
            includehead]{geometry}%Maße für die wissenschaftliche Arbeit
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% now is default encoding 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Silbentrennung
\usepackage[english]{babel} %Sprachanpassungen
 
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}                % <-- new
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, % Tabellen
            threeparttable}     % new 
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}OX}{#1}}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\bfseries}%for formating tags (in table, in items)

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % newest version
\usepackage{siunitx}% instead of units, which is deprecate
\usepackage[skip=1ex, format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}     % new
%\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % changed, instead of "color" and "colortbl"
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.90,0.90,0.90}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Reaction mixture used for the synthesis of cyclohexanone 4-nitrophenylhydrazone.}
\label{tab:ReactionMixtureCyclohexanone4-nitrophenylhydrazone}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{l 
                                    S[table-format=3.2]
                                    S[table-format=4.0]
                                    S[table-format=2.0]
                                    S[table-format=1.1]
                                    S[table-format=1.2]
                                    }
    \rowcolor{hellgrau} 
chemicals   & \mcx{$M$\tnote{a} (\si{\gram\per\mole})}  
                & \mcx{$n$\tnote{b} (\si{\gram\per\mole})}  
                    & \mcx{$V$\tnote{c}\par     (\si{\milli\liter})} 
                        & \mcx{$m$\tnote{d}\par     (\si{\gram})}
                            & \mcx{$\varrho$\tnote{e}\par (\si{\gram\per\mole})}          \\
% table body
Cyclohexanone           & 98.14   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\SI{0.5}{\milli\liter} of the distillate} \\
4-Nitrophenyl hydrazine & 153.14  &  26    & {--} & 0.4   & {--}     \\
Sulfuric acid           & 98.08   &  372   &   2  & 3.68  & 1.84    \\
Water                   & 18.02   & 1664   &   3  & 3     & 1.00    \\
Ethanol                 & 47.07   & 1678   &   10 & 7.9   & 0.79    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\item[a]    $M$: Molecular mass
\item[b]    $n$: amount of substance , 
\item[c]    $V$: volume, 
\item[d]    $m$: mass,  
\item[e]    $\varrho$: density .
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- Suggested table design has width of the `\texwidth`, however number of columns cannot be any, if you you like avoid overlaping of cells contents. With other words, it is limited by size column contents.
- In the case that you not have numbers in table, than you can in above MWE use `X` column specifiers and omit use of `\mcx` for use in column headers (but this is not a case in your code example)

IN

Comment: That comes very close to what I want. Can you also explain to me what it is about this \mcx command and what you did with it in the preamble?

Comment: But unfortunately my main concern is still not fixed. I can still see the small vertical lines between the light gray cells. Is it maybe possible to implement the overhang parameters in the \newcommand line for the \mcx command in the preamble? Bernard edited the overhang parameters in this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301036/229635

Comment: @Benson_G, if you inspect MWE preamble carefully, you will find there deifinition for `\mcx`: it is defined by `multicolumn{1}{...X{...}`. Consequently it defined `X` type cells in columns with different column specification. By it is achieved that  all columns with numbers have equal width  and that column headers can have two lines.

Comment: @Benson_G, white vertical lines not exist and they are cannot be seen im my MWE. If you see, thanm, this are artifacts of your pdf viewer.

Comment: I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler implemented in overleaf.

Comment: @Benson_G, sorry, Im focused only to this question. I add some explanation to answer. Hopefully it will clarify answer.

Comment: @Zarko: When you use standard `colortbl`, the resulting PDF has (your are right) no mathematical thin white lines beetween the colored panels... but some PDF engine (and even modern PDF engines) show some thin white lines at some levels of zoom. It's the case of muPDF used in SumatraPDF but probably also in the PDF viewer of Overleaf (but maybe it's the PDF viewer of the browser). That's why I have written tools in the package `nicematrix` to solve that problem...:-)

Comment: But `nicematrix` is more complicated to compile according to what you said. This kills my work flow.

Comment: @Zarko which part of your code makes the table fitting the text width?

Comment: @Benson_G: Actually, It's not  more complicated for the final user... but Overleaf has not the recent versions of the packages...

Comment: @Benson_G, this tiny lines are artifact of pdf viewers. For example, in my Acrobat Reader DC (recent version) they are not visible, in sumatra they are barely visible (all on FHD screens). They are not visible on paper (temporary I can't confirm this by test) . So, the simplest solution is: don't be so picky ... ;-)

Comment: I see. I think I will just give up on it and ignore the white lines.

Comment: @Zarko unfortunately my code does not compile or returns a time out while compilation after I've implemented your suggested code for the table. Can you maybe help me with this?

Comment: @Benson_G, hm, I do not know what is going on at your compilation. I test my MWE on my PC windows machine and installed recent MikTeX. Compilation is fast (~5 seconds), with no errors, no warnings.  I suggest you to ask new, follow up question (with link to this), where you provide MWE, which reproduce your problem. DIfferences between document and my MWE can be in used packages, your new commands etc.

Comment: I solved my problem.

Comment: @Zarko What does the `[1]` and the `{#1}` as well as in the `\newcommand` line for `\mcx` and in the `\renewcommand` line before the start of the `tabularx`environment do?

Comment: @Benson_G, you mean `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`? This command change position of cells content baseline from top  to its vertical center.  First 1 means, that command has one option, the #1 indicate, where this option is used. Never ever change these settings!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116687/discussion-between-benson-g-and-zarko).

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{-}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of my table\tabularnote{A tabular note.}}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{c-c-c-c-c}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{lightgray}{1}
\Body
  Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 \\
  text & text & text & text & text \\
  text & text & text & text & text \\
  text & text & text & text & text \\
  text & text & text & text & text \\
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This looks quite good. Can you maybe explain to which parameter I have to change when I want to add or delete columns or rows? Also is there a way to use own colors defined bei the colorist package? Best, Benson_G

Comment: Is it also possible to add caption referring as a table to it?

Comment: If you want to add a column, you add a `-c` in the format (that is to say the `{c-c-c-c-c}` in my example). Instead of the color `lightgray`, you can use whatever color defined by the usual tools (for example `\newrgbcolor`). You can insert a `{NiceTabular}*` in an environment `{table}` and use `\caption` exactly as you would do with `{tabular*}`.

Comment: Can you show the syntax to me? I don't know how to add a comment with a MWE.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Your modified code doesn't work me. Does it maybe have anything to do with what you said before: I several compilations? What does that mean?

Comment: Maybe your TeX installation is not up-to-date. Maybe you have not compiled several times. That means: you execute `pdflatex doc.tex`. The PDF is generated but informations are also written on the `doc.aux`. When running `pdflatex doc.tex` once ago, `pdflatex` uses `doc.aux` file and so the (new) PDF is not the same as the first one. If you want, send me a an email: `fpantigny@wanadoo.fr`.

Comment: This sounds quite complicated. I'm using overleaf which I expect to be pretty much up to date.

Comment: Overleaf always does the successive compilations but the version of `nicematrix` available in Overleaf is not the latest... If you want, I can send you the latest.