# Creating a Table fitting the line width and without thin white vertical lines between color filled cells

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, colortbl

Can some help me making the table coded in this Thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301036/229635 fit the line width?

As a MWE I copied the code from the Thread I attached as a link.

Thanks a lot,
Cheers Benson_G

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, enabledeprecatedfontcommands, toc = sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl} %Art des Dokuments, Schriftgröße etc. , idxtotoc, bibtotoc,
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin=2cm, includehead]{geometry}%Maße für die wissenschaftliche Arbeit
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
 \definecolor{gr}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
    \hhline{----}
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}m{.1\textwidth}} {Here's a box\\ Score} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}m{.3\textwidth}}{Here's a box\\ Score}
                        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0pt\relax]}m{.3\textwidth}}{Another Box\\ with two Rows} %
                                    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\tabcolsep]}m{.3\textwidth}|}{Student's\\ Proficiency Level}
    \tabularnewline%
    \hline
    Science     & 28    & 26 or above     & Proficient\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you already try to replace {11cm} with {\textwidth}?

Comment: @leandriis yes I did. It didn't work.

Comment: What exactly does "it does not work"  mean? Do you get a different output than the expected or an error message? Please clarify.

Comment: I just updated my MWE and attached a picture of the output.

Comment: Add `\noindent` right before `\begin{tabularx}`. Also, it does not really make sense to use tabularx without any `X` type column. In the previous version of your question, there was an `X` type column present. Your table currently is wider than the textwidth, since you did not take into account the value of `\tabcosep` when calculating the column widths.

Comment: `\noindent` fixed the gap between the table and the left page border but the overlap on the right side remains. I have updated the MWE and the output picture again.

Comment: I want to use `tabularx`because I want to get rid of the white thin vertical lines between the color filled cells.

Comment: `tabularx` is not the problem per se. The issue here is that you use it while not declaring any `X` type columns in your table. Replace all instances of `m{.3\textwidth}` with `X` and your table should be just as wide as the textwidth.

Comment: Okay if `tabularx`is not the problem I would highly appreciated a solution using only `tabulator anything else which is simpler to use. :D

Comment: @leandriis Do you literally mean to replace all `m{.3\textwidth}`by `X` ?

Comment: Yes. As I already mentioned earlier: tabularx needs at least one X type column to properly "do its magic".

Comment: @leandriis Replacing the `m{.3\textwidth}`by `X`makes it even worse but I think I most probably did it wrong. See updated MWE and output Picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first rough version of your table that now fits into the textwidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, toc = sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % replaces above two lines
 \definecolor{gr}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.1\textwidth}YYY}
        \hhline{----}
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}m{.1\textwidth}} {Here's a box\\ Score} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}X}{Here's a box\\ Score}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0pt\relax]}X}{Another Box\\ with two Rows} %
                                        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\tabcolsep]}X|}{Student's\\ Proficiency Level}
        \tabularnewline%
        \hline
        Science     & 28    & 26 or above     & Proficient\tabularnewline
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

---

With the help of `cellspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, toc = sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin=2cm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % replaces above two lines
 \definecolor{gr}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{20pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.1\textwidth}YYY}
        \hhline{----}
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}0{m{.1\textwidth}}} {Here's a box\\ Score} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}0{X}}{Here's a box\\ Score}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0pt\relax]}0{X}}{Another Box\\ with two Rows} %
                                        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\tabcolsep]}0{X}|}{Student's\\ Proficiency Level}
        \tabularnewline%
        \hline
        Science     & 28    & 26 or above     & Proficient\tabularnewline
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is working pretty well. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Two last questions: Is there a way to 1. increase the row height of only the first row and 2. to add some vertical space only between the first and the second row?

Comment: You could use the `cellspace` package. I have just updated my answer to include a second example that demostrates the use of the before mentioned package. I used exaggerated values just to show the effect more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys and @leandriis,

I could manage to solve my problems by myself.

Here is what the final code looks like....just in case you are interested:
It includes a way:

1. to solve the prob with white thin vertical lines between the color filled cells by using @leandriis code in this thread above
2. to only change the row height of the first row by using

```
\usepackage{stackengine} % Package to change row height
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
```

in the preamble and `\xrowht{10pt}`within the multicolumn curly brackets for text. ([How to specify the row height in LaTeX table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table/19594))

3. to add vertical space only between two specific cells with `\addlinespace[0.2cm]` right after the command for a new tabular line ([Inserting a small vertical space in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50352/inserting-a-small-vertical-space-in-a-table))

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, enabledeprecatedfontcommands, toc = sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl} %Art des Dokuments, Schriftgröße etc. , idxtotoc, bibtotoc,
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin=2cm, includehead]{geometry}%Maße für die wissenschaftliche Arbeit
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} %Bessere Seitenumbrüche
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Silbentrennung
\usepackage[german]{babel} %Sprachanpassungen
\usepackage{ragged2e} %für Blocksatzschalter \justifying
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Direkte Angabe von Umlauten möglich 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einfügen von Bildern
% \usepackage{tabularx} %Tabellen
% \usepackage{booktabs} %Weitere Möglichkeiten für Tabellen
\usepackage{here} %Lage von Tabellen und Bildern 
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % be sure to specify the option 'hyphens'
% \usepackage[pdftex,bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
% \usepackage[superscript]{cite}

% ======SCHRIFTART=================================

% Schriftart Helvetica
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% ===================================================

\usepackage[per-mode = reciprocal, output-decimal-marker={,}, exponent-product = {\cdot}]{siunitx} %Si-Einheiten


\usepackage[headsepline,automark, draft = false]{scrlayer-scrpage} %Für Kopf und Fußzeile und Seitenzahlen
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead{\pagemark}
% \cfoot{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}

%=======TABELLEN=====================================
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}  

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{stackengine} % Für Zeilenabstand
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % newest version
\usepackage{siunitx}% instead of units, which is deprecate
\sisetup{detect-weight,detect-mode}%Si-Einheiten
\usepackage[labelsep = period, skip=1ex, format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf, justification = justified]{caption}     % new
%\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{ExpBlau}{rgb}{0.11,0.19,0.46}
\definecolor{gr}{rgb}{0.90,0.90,0.90}

%=====================================================
%=====================================================

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabelle}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}
\captionsetup[table]{justification = raggedright, font=normal, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{table}[htb!]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\belowcaptionskip{5 pt}
  \caption{\textbf{Molekulare Eigenschaften der P(EO-\textit{co}-EPB)-Copolymere$^{\textcolor{ExpBlau}a}$}}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.04\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.185\textwidth}YYYY}
    
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}}m{.04\textwidth}} {\xrowht{10pt}Nr.} 
                    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0.3pt\relax]}m{.185\textwidth}} {\xrowht{10pt}Copolymer} 
                            & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0.3pt\relax]}X}{\xrowht{10pt}$\textit{M}_\text{n, NMR}$ (\si{\gram\per\mole})}
                                        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0.3pt\relax]}X}{\xrowht{10pt} mol\% EPB$^{\textcolor{ExpBlau}c}$} %
                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0.3pt\relax]}X}{\xrowht{10pt}$\textit{M}_\text{n, GPC}$ (\si{\gram\per\mole})} %
                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{gr}[\tabcolsep]}X}{\xrowht{10pt} \textit{Đ}}
        \tabularnewline\addlinespace[0.2cm]  
                                                                                                                                                          %  SASSK
                            1                             &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   113
                            2                             &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   114
           \hspace{ 0.5mm}  3$^{\textcolor{ExpBlau}b}$    &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   101
                            4                             &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   111
                            5                             &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   105
                            6                             &    ThatsALongWord    &  xxxx  &  x,x  &  xxxx  &  x,xx \tabularnewline      %   112
\end{tabularx}
    \vspace{0.6 \baselineskip} \\
    \justifying
    $^{\textcolor{ExpBlau}a}$ Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
  \label{tab:Copo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```