# why does alternating color of table faintly color vertical lines too?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{default}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{r|rrrrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \hline
1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  7 & 1.28 & -0.46 & 1.33 & -0.66 & -1.80 \\
  8 & 0.80 & 0.46 & 1.37 & 1.73 & 1.93 \\
  9 & -0.75 & 0.28 & 0.51 & 0.19 & 0.58 \\
  10 & -1.64 & -0.12 & -1.17 & -0.10 & -0.04 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

faintly colors vertical lines too, how to avoid?:
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you see if this question and the @Bernard 's answer is it fine for you :-)?https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300994/eliminating-little-white-vertical-lines-in-tabular-caused-by-colortbl-colorcell To me seem a duplicate your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think that what you see is mostly aliasing and/or effect of the viewer antialiasing algorithms. Your code, using `okular`, 1600% magnification, color picked:

[image]

[image]

If the effect annoys you, you can remove all the vertical lines and play with spaces and styles:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{default}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}rrrrrr}
  \toprule
  \qquad & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \midrule
  1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  7 & 1.28 & -0.46 & 1.33 & -0.66 & -1.80 \\
  8 & 0.80 & 0.46 & 1.37 & 1.73 & 1.93 \\
  9 & -0.75 & 0.28 & 0.51 & 0.19 & 0.58 \\
  10 & -1.64 & -0.12 & -1.17 & -0.10 & -0.04 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive answer :-)

Comment: Well, I teach analog electronics, and aliasing is one of my pet-peeves. If you only knew the number of papers I reviewed getting it wrong...

Comment: ok I see the lines fluctuate as I zoom. So I guess this is nothing I can fix in my doc, just an artifact of viewing?

Comment: @curious exactly. In addition, there can be also an effect of vision here: https://slate.com/technology/2013/12/optical-illusion-shades-of-gray.html

Answer (score 4):

The package `nicematrix` has tools specifically designed to solve that kind of problems.

The environment `{NiceTabular}` draws the colored cells, rows and columns *before* the rules. The resulting PDF is much easier to interpret by the PDF viewers and you won't have the effect you see by using the package `colortbl` (which is loaded by the key `table` of `xcolor`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{default}

\begin{center}

\begin{NiceTabular}{r|rrrrr}
\CodeBefore
   \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\Body
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \hline
1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  7 & 1.28 & -0.46 & 1.33 & -0.66 & -1.80 \\
  8 & 0.80 & 0.46 & 1.37 & 1.73 & 1.93 \\
  9 & -0.75 & 0.28 & 0.51 & 0.19 & 0.58 \\
  10 & -1.64 & -0.12 & -1.17 & -0.10 & -0.04 \\
   \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]